# Custom serializer with polymorphic kotlinx serialization

Tags: kotlin, serialization, polymorphism, kotlinx.serialization

With kotlinx.serialization polymorphism, I want to get

```
{"type":"veh_t","owner":"Ivan","bodyType":"cistern","carryingCapacityInTons":5,"detachable":false}
```

but I get

```
{"type":"kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap","owner":"Ivan","bodyType":"cistern","carryingCapacityInTons":5,"detachable":false}
```

I use the following models

```
interface Vehicle {
    val owner: String
}

@Serializable
@SerialName("veh_p")
data class PassengerCar(
    override val owner: String,
    val numberOfSeats: Int
) : Vehicle

@Serializable
@SerialName("veh_t")
data class Truck(
    override val owner: String,
    val body: Body
) : Vehicle {
    @Serializable
    data class Body(
        val bodyType: String,
        val carryingCapacityInTons: Int,
        val detachable: Boolean
        //a lot of other fields
    )    
}
```

I apply the following Json

```
inline val VehicleJson: Json get() = Json(context = SerializersModule {
        polymorphic(Vehicle::class) {
            PassengerCar::class with PassengerCar.serializer()
            Truck::class with TruckKSerializer
        }
    })
```

I use serializer TruckKSerializer because the server adopts a flat structure. At the same time, in the application I want to use an object Truck.Body. For flatten I override `fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj : T)` and `fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): T` in Serializator using JsonOutput and JsonInput according to the documentation in these classes.

```
object TruckKSerializer : KSerializer<Truck> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = SerialClassDescImpl("Truck")

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj: Truck) {
        val output = encoder as? JsonOutput ?: throw SerializationException("This class can be saved only by Json")
        output.encodeJson(json {
            obj::owner.name to obj.owner
            encoder.json.toJson(Truck.Body.serializer(), obj.body)
                .jsonObject.content
                .forEach { (name, value) ->
                    name to value
                }
        })
    }

    @ImplicitReflectionSerializer
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Truck {
        val input = decoder as? JsonInput
            ?: throw SerializationException("This class can be loaded only by Json")
        val tree = input.decodeJson() as? JsonObject
            ?: throw SerializationException("Expected JsonObject")
        return Truck(
            tree.getPrimitive("owner").content,
            VehicleJson.fromJson<Truck.Body>(tree)
        )
    }
}
```

And finally, I use `stringify(serializer: SerializationStrategy<T>, obj: T)`

```
VehicleJson.stringify(
    PolymorphicSerializer(Vehicle::class),
    Truck(
        owner = "Ivan",
        body = Truck.Body(
            bodyType = "cistern",
            carryingCapacityInTons = 5,
            detachable = false
        )
    )
)
```

I end up with `{"type":"kotlin.collections.LinkedHashMap", ...}`, but I need `{"type":"veh_t", ...}`
How do I get the right type? I want using polymorphism for `Vehicle` and encode Body object with Truck.Body.serializer() to flatten.

With this serialization, the PassengerCar class runs fine.

```
VehicleJson.stringify(
    PolymorphicSerializer(Vehicle::class),
    PassengerCar(
        owner = "Oleg",
        numberOfSeats = 4
    )
)
```

Result is correct:

```
{"type":"veh_p","owner":"Oleg","numberOfSeats":4}
```

I think the problem is the custom serializer `TruckKSerializer`.
And I noticed if I use in my overridden `fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, obj : T)` next code

```
encoder
            .beginStructure(descriptor)
            .apply { 
                //...
            }
            .endStructure(descriptor)
```

I get the correct type but cannot flatten the object Truck.Body using its serializer.

Answer (score 0):

the correct way to open and close a composite `{}`
is this code

```
val composite = encoder.beginStructure(descriptor)
// use composite instead of encoder here
composite.endStructure(descriptor)
```

and you should be able to serialize `Body` using `.encodeSerializable(Body.serializer(), body)`

and always pass the descriptor along otherwise it will fall back to stuff like that LinkedhashMap for the json dictionary

Comment: In this case, you must specify the position of the element in the descriptor use `fun encodeStringElement (desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int, value: String)` or `fun <T : Any?> encodeSerializableElement(desc: SerialDescriptor, index: Int, serializer: SerializationStrategy<T>, value: T)` or something else. Is it possible to avoid this?
And `.encodeSerializable(Body.serializer(), body)` inside beginStructure/endStructure forms something like `{commonFields, {bodyFields}}` But I need a flat structure `{commonFields, bodyFields}``.